# Using the MensurationDockWin in ArcObjects .Net

Tags: arcobjects, c#, dockable-window

I have a DockableWindow add-in that had it's own map control.  I would like to be able to use the mensuration tools from the Image Analysis window.

[image]

I can add the standard Measure Tool with the following code, but it doesn't have desired tools. Namely Point Location and Base to Top Height.

```
ControlsMapMeasureTool measureTool = new ControlsMapMeasureTool();
measureTool.OnCreate(axMapControl1.Object);
axMapControl1.CurrentTool = (ITool)measureTool;
```

I've tried looking for how to create/use the [MensurationDockWin](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-java/api/arcobjects/com/esri/arcgis/arcmapui/MensurationDockWin.html), or even the [ImageAnalysisWindowCommand](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/java/api/arcobjects/com/esri/arcgis/arcmapui/ImageAnalysisWindowCommand.html), but I'm not sure how to go about utilizing Esri Dockable windows.

I've tried the following, but whenever OnCreate is call it throws an AccessViolationException [Trying to read/write protected memory]

```
MensurationDockWin mensurationWindow = new MensurationDockWin();
mensurationWindow.OnCreate(axMapControl1.Object);

ImageAnalysisWindowCommand window = new ImageAnalysisWindowCommand();
window.OnCreate(axMapControl1.Object);
```